# Base Constructor is Not Getting Called

Tags: c#, constructor

I am having an issue where the base constructor for a derived class is not getting executed.  I have done this a hundred times and I cannot figure out for the life of me why the base constructor is not executing.  I'm hoping that someone can find something simple that I am missing.  An example of the code is below.  Does anyone have any idea why my base constructor is not getting called first?  I have other classes that are implemented in the same fashion and the base constructor is always called first.

```
if (item.GetType() == typeof(OtherChargeItem))
{
    OtherChargeItemAddUpdateTest test = new OtherChargeItemAddUpdateTest((OtherChargeItem)item);
    test.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    test.ShowDialog();
}

public OtherChargeItemAddUpdateTest()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public OtherChargeItemAddUpdateTest(OtherChargeItem item)
        : base()
{
    currentItem = item;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the inheritance hierarchy here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like you want to call the default constructor in the same class, not the base class, so `InitializeComponent` gets called when the second constructor gets called. Try `this()` instead of `base()`.

Comment: +1 Yes, good deduction skills. He probably thinks that the default constructor is called the "base constructor".

Comment: Thanks, I was just getting ready to express how dumb I feel right now.  As soon as JaredPar asked for the inheritance hierarchy I realized the flaw in my description of the problem and what I have been trying to do for the past 30 minutes.  Thanks for the help and sorry for wasting everyone's time with such a trivial question that wasn't so trivial for my brain this morning for some reason.

Comment: What is protocol on something like this?  Should I modify the question to better reflect what my question should have been?